# Using models relationships in Laravel Validation Rule 'Exists'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-validation

Db schema

```
users
 -id
 -name
 -email
 ...

roles
 -id
 -name
```

> User may have multiple roles and vice-versa (i already defined
>   relationships in models)

pivot table

```
role_user
 -id
 -user_id
 -role_id
```

Validation rule trying to make: user_id must exist in users table and has role id = 4

```
//...
'user_id' => ['nullable', Rule::exists('users')->where(
                function ($query) { 
                    $query->whereHas('roles', 
                        function ($q) { 
                            $q->where('id', 4); 
                        }
                    );
                }
)], 
//...
```

> Error message : "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown
>   column 'has' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from
>   `users` where `user_id` = 0 and (`has` = roles))"

Comment: hi. you want validation the incoming user rule right?

Comment: do the user exist different and role different.

Comment: @MohammadaliMirhamed no, i would like to validate a string like "1", "2" received from api body request

Comment: @hasan05 could you provide more details ?

Comment: Is this for api validation ?

Comment: you just want to know is 1 or 2 in your role-user table ?

Comment: @hasan05 yes for api validation

Comment: @MohammadaliMirhamed i want to make sure user_id exists in my users table and the user that has this id has a particular role

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use this. This will solve your problem, but i don't know either is the best way or not.

```
    use Validator; // on the top

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'user_id' => 'nullable|numeric|exists:users,id',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {            
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
    }
    $user = User::find($request->user_id);
    if(!$user || !$user->roles->first() || $user->roles->first()->id != 4) {
        return response()->json(['user_id'=>['You dont have permission.']], 422);
    }
```

Another way you can try

```
'user_id'  => [
            'nullable',
            'numeric',
            'exists:users,id',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) { 
                $editorsIDs = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
                    $q->where('id', 4);
                })->pluck('id');

                if(! $editorsIDs->contains($value)) {                        
                    $fail('You dont have permission.');
                }}
            ]
```

Comment: 'user_id' must exists in users table

Comment: how can i chain user_id validation with others attrs

Comment: there is another way may, you may try. updated on previous answer.

Comment: we could add by `$validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!');` I think.
if you have time, have a look on laravel documentation. :)
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation
and also, dont forget to "mark as accepted answer", If it solves your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

I resolve it using

```
$usersWhereHasEditorRole = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
     $q->where('id', 4);
})->pluck('id')->unique('id')->toArray();

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'name' => 'required|alpha', // commun
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users', // commun
                'password' => 'required|min:8|regex:/[a-z]/|regex:/[A-Z]/|regex:/[0-9]/|regex:/[@$!%*#?&]/', // commun
                'c_password' => 'required|same:password', // commun
                //...
                'user_id' => ['nullable', Rule::in($usersWhereHasEditorRole)],
                //...
]);


if ($validator->fails()) {
      return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors(), 400);
}

dd('passes');
```